# Your src appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client',but you'll need to use the <src> directive in your module to make it accessible

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using GWT 2.9.0 + GXT 4.1.0 + Java 11 combination. I am getting below error
**[ERROR] Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client'; no problem, but you'll need to use the  directive in your module to make it accessible
ProjectName**. Below is my project structure in package explorer in eclipse.  I am getting the error when trying to run my application in super dev mode through gwt eclipse plugin in eclipse IDE. Can you help me in resolving the issue

MavenProjectName

src/main/java ----> This is empty

src/main/src-client

```
com.cname.proj
  Main.java
   Main.gwt.xml 
com.cname.proj.client.centerpanelscreens
com.cname.proj.client.command
com.cname.proj.service
```

src/main/src-common

```
  com.cname.proj
     Common.gwt.xml
com.cname.proj.model
com.cname.proj.model.to
com.cname.proj.service
com.cname.proj.util
```

src/main/webapp

```
    index.html
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

```
     web.xml    
      
Content below in Main.gwt.xml 
     
<module rename-to="js">
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
<inherits name='com.cname.proj.Common' />
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>

<entry-point class='com.cname.proj.Main' />
<source path="client" />
<source path="service"/>
</module>

Content below in Common.gwt.xml 

<module>
  <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
<source path="model"/>
<source path="service" />
<source path="util">
</source>
```

GWT Logs

```
 Resolving javax.validation.constraints.Pattern
   Resolving javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.Flag
      Found type 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.Flag'
         Resolving method <clinit>
         Resolving method <init>
         Resolving method getValue
         Resolving method values
         Resolving method valueOf
         Resolving field UNIX_LINES
         Resolving field CASE_INSENSITIVE
         Resolving field COMMENTS
         Resolving field MULTILINE
         Resolving field DOTALL
         Resolving field UNICODE_CASE
         Resolving field CANON_EQ
         Resolving field value
   Resolving javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.List
      Found type 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.List'
         Resolving annotation for java.lang.annotation.Target
         Resolving annotation for java.lang.annotation.Retention
         Resolving annotation for java.lang.annotation.Documented
         Resolving method value
   Resolving javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState
   Finding entry point classes
      Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.cname.proj.Main'
         Checked 0 dependencies for errors.
      [ERROR] Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client'; no problem, but you'll need to use the <source> directive in your module to make it accessible
Closing cache file: C:\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-b9eb8fcc22822eac5087fcda1c6dcb20c0796e62-18CAE75E829AF224BF18DEE97AC379EF-00000181BAD760BD (0 units written)
Deleting empty file: C:\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-b9eb8fcc22822eac5087fcda1c6dcb20c0796e62-18CAE75E829AF224BF18DEE97AC379EF-00000181BAD760BD
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

POM.xml with the required legacy plugin

```
<plugins>
  <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test</goal>
          <!-- goal>generateAsync</goal> -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
      documentation at codehaus.org -->
    <configuration>
      <!-- module>com.msci.dm.gis.gwt.Main</module-->
      <runTarget>Main.html</runTarget>
      <debugPort>8998</debugPort>
      <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
      <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
    </configuration>`enter code here`
  </plugin>
```

Comment: How is your pom set up? Can you share the rest of the gwt-maven-plugin logs?

Comment: Hi  Colin, I have edited my question and have added some part of the logs and I have added the legacy plugin for GWT. Please lt me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.cname.proj.Main'
>   Checked 0 dependencies for errors.
>     [ERROR] Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client'; no problem, but you'll need to use the <source> directive in your module to make it accessible
> ```

Your .gwt.xml files both live in com/cname/proj/, and only lists these sub-packages as sources:

> ```
> <source path="client" />
> <source path="service" />
> ...
> <source path="model" />
> <source path="service" />
> <source path="util" />
> ```

(note that you have "service" listed twice, both .gwt.xml files claim that the server package is part of its own module).

Since no module is claiming the top-level package of com.cname.proj, that source file will not be available at compile time.

---

The expected pattern is to only list packages that are expected for the compiler to transform all of their contents into JS. Typically, this is the `client` sub-package, but convention often suggests that a `shared` sub-package may exist too, consisting of code shared between the server and client. There is no problem with listing others like `service`, `model`, `util`, and you technically can also just list the empty string to indicate the entire current package and all subpackages:

```
<source path="" />
```

---

With all of that said, the best option is to move `Main` into `com.cname.proj.client`, since it is almost certainly exclusively a client class.

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue but now I am stuck at a different issue.

Now my project structure related to webapp is below as folllows:

MavenProjectName

src/main/webapp
      gxt -----> Some folder and files 
      js  -----> Some folder and files '
     index.html
     proj.css
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF    
         web.xml       -----> Some servlets, their mappings and index.html in welcome-file-list tag

But still I am not able to see the application hostpage
Scenario 1)
Scenario 1)
Now If I start codeserver then from the GWT eclipse plugin then it displays a blank page

Comment: Please open a new question, with all of the details of this - console logs, browser logs, expected paths to files, etc.